# Does the legend of Satyavrata include a part where he becomes drunk?

Tags: manu

This is somewhat related to [this other question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6969/manu-and-the-great-deluge) about Manu and the great deluge.

An old book I was reading (titled "The Testimony of the Rocks" by Hugh Miller) said [on p. 290](https://books.google.com/books?id=8h5GAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA290) about Satyavrata that

> that the good man having, on one occasion long after, by "the act of
> destiny," drunk mead, he became senseless, and lay asleep naked, and
> that Charma, one of three sons who had been born to him, finding him
> in that sad state, called on his two brothers to witness the shame of
> their father, and said to them, What has now befallen? In what state
> is this our sire?
>
> But by the two brothers, - more dutiful than Charma, - he was hidden
> with clothes, and recalled to his senses; and, having recovered his
> intellect, and perfectly knowing what had passed, he cursed Charma,
> saying, "Thou shalt be a servant of servants."

Hugh Miller does not specify where in the sacred scriptures this is found, so I thought I ask about it here.

1. Does the legend of Satyavrata include an episode such as told above,
   and if so, where is that found?
2. In this narrative is Satyavrata the same as Manu or are they two
   separate persons?